# Array of special characters in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I want to create an array of special characters in Objective C, I created it as following but have an error:

```
NSArray *charactersAndSymbolsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    @"0",@"1",@"2",@"3", @"4",@"5",@"6",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",
    @"@",@"%",@"+",@"\",@"/",@"'",@"!",@"#",@"$",@"^",@"?",@":",@".",@"(",@")",@"{",@"}",@"[",@"]",@"~",nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

This character is causing the error:

```
@"\"
```

The backslash is an escape character for the " - the quotes are interpreted 'literally', not as the end of the string.
Change it to:

```
@"\\"
```

Comment: You're welcome. In the future, please post your code in the question and do not use upload sites.

Comment: Ok, I tried to post code on this site but I was denied by this site. Could u please guide me to post code on this site?

Comment: When you click the 'edit' link under the question, you can see how it looks like now. For more help, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) link.